# Errors from different form goes to catch on other form

Tags: vb.net, forms, try-catch

I would be grateful if you could help me with a strange behavior on a vb.net project.

I have a Login form. 
The user gives username and password and if the credentials are ok, the app goes to another form

```
Try
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand("Select * From users where username = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and userpass = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'", con)
        Dim dr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(dr)
        If dt.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            'there is only one user
            Dim f As New MainFrm
            f.lbluser.Tag = dt.Rows(0)(3)
            f.lbluser.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1)
            f.ShowDialog()
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            'credentials are wrong
            MessageBox.Show("No user with those credentials. Try again!", "Wrong credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
            PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
            UsernameTextBox.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'credentials are multiple in the database
            MessageBox.Show("Issues with the credentials. Code error: LFUE-1010", "Multiple users | LFUE-1010", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        'there are problems with the connection / or sql
        MessageBox.Show("Connection issues - code error: LFDC-1020 " & ex.Message, "DB connection error | LFDC-1020", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

This works perfectly.
In the other form, let's say that I have a button:

```
If cbkeywords.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("select something")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim d = DirectCast(cbkeywords.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("Keyword")
    If lstkeywords.Items.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstkeywords.Items.Count - 1
            If lstkeywords.Items(i).contains(d) Then
                MessageBox.Show("there is already value " & d, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dtkeys.Rows.Add(cbkeywords.SelectedValue, d)
                lstkeywords.Items.Add(d)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        dtkeys.Rows.Add(cbkeywords.SelectedValue, d)
        lstkeywords.Items.Add(d)
    End If
```

if the code has an error then the app goes to Login Form Catch ex As Exception and get the message.

Wherever I have issues with code in different forms, the app goes to Login Form Catch ex As Exception.

I cleaned solution, project, restart but nothing changed.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `f.ShowDialog() => f.Show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the database code first and then do the other code. Keep them separate. Otherwise, when you do `f.ShowDialog()`, it is still inside the Try...Catch.

Something like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim con As New SqliteConnection(yourConnectionString)

Try
    Dim sql As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand("Select * From users where username = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and userpass = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'", con)
    Dim dr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader()
    dt.Load(dr)

Catch ex As Exception
    con.Close()
    'there are problems with the connection / or sql
    MessageBox.Show("Connection issues - code error: LFDC-1020 " & ex.Message, "DB connection error | LFDC-1020", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

Finally
    If Sql IsNot Nothing Then
        Sql.Dispose()
    End If

    If con IsNot Nothing Then
        con.Dispose()
    End If

End Try

If dt.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    'there is only one user
    Dim f As New MainFrm
    f.lbluser.Tag = dt.Rows(0)(3)
    f.lbluser.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1)
    f.ShowDialog()
    Me.Close()
ElseIf dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    'credentials are wrong
    MessageBox.Show("No user with those credentials. Try again!", "Wrong credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
    PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
    UsernameTextBox.Focus()
    Exit Sub
Else
    'credentials are multiple in the database
    MessageBox.Show("Issues with the credentials. Code error: LFUE-1010", "Multiple users | LFUE-1010", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You do not need to open the connection because the `.Load` method does that and then leaves the connection in the state it was.

Comment: Do the SQLite objects implement IDisposable? Then the objects should use `Using` instead of explicit `.Dispose` calls.

Comment: @HardCode It wasn't clear where `con` was coming from, so I left it as a Try...Catch to emphasise making a new connection. A Try...Catch would still be needed around the Using, and using the Finally clause makes it equivalent to a Using statement anyway. I would usually suggest code with Using.